# Pandas - Get outliers with condition from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with two columns:

```
'Transmission' (object)
'City MPG (FT1)' (int64)
```

The boxplot shows that there are value to a couple of transmissions that are outliers. Manual 5-Speed (one type of transmission that is in the 'Transmission' column) has a lot if outlier values.

I thought of deleting the rows with outliers by checking the values with quantiles.

```
q_99 = data["City MPG (FT1)"].quantile(0.99)
q_1 = data["City MPG (FT1)"].quantile(0.01)
```

And then checking the rows with the outliers like this:

```
data[(data["City MPG (FT1)"] > q_99) | (data["City MPG (FT1)"] < q_1)]
```

So every value above 0.99 quantile and every value below 0.01 quantile. But this way it simple gets the outliers without the associated transmission from the 'Transmission' column. How can I add the condition and whats the code to delete those row?

Edit:
I can't post the whole DF because it has 32k rows and thats too much to show.
Here are the 10 first rows of the Dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Transmission':['Manual 5-Speed',
                                     'Manual 5-Speed',
                                     'Manual 5-Speed',
                                     'Manual 5-Speed',
                                     'Automatic 3-Speed',
                                     'Automatic 3-Speed',
                                     'Automatic 3-Speed',
                                     'Automatic 3-Speed',
                                     'Automatic 3-Speed',
                                     'Automatic 3-Speed'],
                      'City MPG (FT1)':[17,17,18,
                                        18,18,18,
                                        13,13,15,16]})
```

Comment: Do you mind to share with us a part of your original df? Possibly with `df.to_dict()`. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i will. But i will show you guys just a part of it because it has 32k of rows.

Comment: Please check your `data`  the second column has 9 elements while the first one has 10. Then whit your data there are not value outside the quantile

Comment: please correct typos in `data[(data["City MPG (FT1)"] > q_100) | (data["City MPG (FT1)"] < q_0)]` too

Comment: Anyway, beside typos, for me it's working. I mean i can see both of the columns

Comment: But how can i get the outliners for 'Manual 5-Speed' and 'Automatic 3-Speed'? The way i do it it calculates the outliners using all values combined without grouping it to the different transmissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a column to your original dataframe so you can test it.

```
def fun(x):
    q_99 = x.quantile(0.99)
    q_1 = x.quantile(0.01)
    return (x>q_99) | (x<q_1)

data["is_outlier"] = data.groupby("Transmission")["City MPG (FT1)"].transform(lambda x: fun(x))
```

Now you can filter using this column.